# Tableau Web Data Connector hosted in a Cloud Platform getting stuck in infinite loop

Tags: tableau-api

I have this TWDC(tableau web data connector) app hosted on our company's private cloud.
Every app that are deployed there are accessed after the user logs in via a Single Sign On login page, then redirected to the app.

When I try to use my web data connector on my Tableau Desktop it gets stuck on an infinite loop, after i push the button which does `tableau.submit()`.

I've set the debugger and found out, that when I push the button, the page that is loaded is not the index.html of my WDC but the redirect page from the SSO login.
I have no idea why is this happening, doesn't make much sense, because it loaded the index.html in the first place, but after i push this button it gets back to somewhere in the middle of SSO login and redirect page.

**Just a note: It works fine on the simulator.**

Any thougths on this?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TableauAngular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/tableauwdc-2.3.latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="submitButton">Send</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <textarea id="log" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; height: 700px;"></textarea>
  <br />
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  try {

    $("#submitButton").click(function() { tableau.submit() });

    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // these are function which are not important for this question;
    myConnector.getSchema = fnGetSchema; 
    myConnector.getData = fnGetData;

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);

  } catch (e) {
    logger("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your code.  With the WDC there is an interactive phase where the user is shown a screen and can interact (this is your first SSO sign-in) but then there is a non-interactive (Get Data) phase where Tableau will try to retrieve the data and never shows the SSO login to the user.  See [docs](https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_phases.html).  Given this page is loaded without user interaction it can't/shouldn't have SSO security on it.

Comment: Your response makes sense, now I understand the difference between “phases”. So basically, you’re saying that, there is no workaround this? :( I don’t believe that in the company we’re able to publish this on an external domain with a custom authentication.

Comment: The workaround would be to setup a server that doesn't require authentication.  While it isn't really recommended, you could even stand up a lightweight server on the Tableau Server and maybe you wouldn't need to go through the SSO authentication in that case?  But otherwise, no, I don't know of any workaround.